# Are there Web-Safe fonts that have a center-bar on the 7?

Tags: css, fonts, typography

I want to know if there are any web-safe fonts that have a center bar on the character for 7 (seven), as I tried to search but couldn't find.
I know I could use google fonts, but I want to loading time very low.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any specific fonts that are safe for web and fulfill your needs as there aren't too many of them.

If you are willing to use `font-face`, you can change the sample text to "7" in **Google fonts** and find a bunch of them quickly. Here are some of them:

- Patrick Hand
- Bad Script
- Rock Salt
- Cookie
- Permanent Marker
- Kaushan Script
- Dancing Script
- Indie Flower

Comment: Actually, I meant I was looking for web-safe fonts already in the users devices, so they wouldn't have to download those fonts, thanks for those fonts anyway!

Comment: My bad. I updated the answer to better fit the question.

Comment: The concept of web-safe fonts no longer exists. There are so many different devices out there, you won't find a font that exists on literally all of them. Use a webfont or create an image.